# Animated GIF CSS background not showing all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animated-gif

I need an animated gif to appear, so I style it as the css background, but it doesn't show all the time.

What happens is on pinch in of the ( . polaroid ), I scale the height of the ( `.poaroid` ). Now, I'm trying to trigger this animated gif poof animation when the scale is less than or equal to 0.42. In other words when the pinch has caused the .polaroid to be 42% or less than its original size.

So if you go to this URL on a multi-touch device: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcTW9BMHg4b0lPUDA/index.html

Then pinch in on the polaroid cards (.polaroid), they get smaller, get them small enough and they are replaced with , but the animation doesn't happen all the time. Why not?

Here is my js:

```
function transform(e){
    var cssScale = "scaleY("+ scaleFactor +")";
    element.css({
        webkitTransform: cssScale,
        webkitTransformOrigin: cssOrigin,
        transform: cssScale,
        transformOrigin: cssOrigin,
    });
    if(scaleFactor <= 0.42){
        $(element).replaceWith('<div class="poof"></div>');
        $('.poof').css('height', itsHeight).css('width', itsWidth).css('background', 'transparent url(poof.gif?v='+time+') center no-repeat');
        time++;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.poof').remove();
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

**The `<div class="poof"></div>` replaces the .polaroid if it is shrunk to 42% or less; however, its background ( the poof animated gif ) doesn't show every time** even though the jQuery writes it as the css background each time.

Comment: Seemed to work fine for me every time I tried. Tried at least 10 times to pinch all 3 pictures. Tried on Chrome in iOS 6, iPhone 4s, if it matters..

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Hmm interesting. It only works once for me on android. Only on the first picture. And I'm running the latest chrome on the latest android.

Comment: The link did not work for me